# How is that the vampires wanted to kill all humans, if they needed humans to feed themselves with blood?

Tags: seraph-of-the-end

In season 2 episode 3 if I recall correctly, a vampire says they have a plan to kill all humans.

How is that the vampires wanted to kill all humans, if they needed humans to feed themselves with blood?

Answer (score 1):

Humans with their greed attempted to take over seraphs and use them as weapons, and after doing stuff such as reseructing death(guren squad) they caused apocalypse after releasing a virus.

Humans killed 90% of their own population.

Reason for seraphs murderous intent against humanity is most likely because of being stuck in human host and experimented on for weaponry.

Vampires apeared after these events, they came out of the underground world to save as many humans(livestock) possible seeing their diminishing numbers.

Therefore if a vampire did say that they would kill humans i highly suspect it is either limited to a certain group or just his personal wish.

Since they initialy came out to preserve the human population.

Answer (score 0):

Vampires know humans are their enemies, so they have to kill humans before they kill them..

It's raise war of survival like all our history.

And if you talk about food.. they will evolve to eat other things to survive as we saw in the anime Prototype.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).